# What can cause a Ubuntu 22.04 system to suddenly become very slow?

Tags: 22.04, performance

I've used my Ubuntu 22.04 installation for around 6 months now for work (software development work). Yesterday morning all was fine as usual, but when I came back from lunch, the entire system was extremely slow.

- Launching applications takes minutes instead of ~1 second
- The system stops responding to input for ~10 seconds and then processes the input

Overall, the system is completely unusable for productive work. I tried:

- Updating all packages via `apt` and `snap`
- Restarting several times
- Removing power from the machine entirely
- Monitoring system resources. RAM, CPU, network and disk are barely used at all (!)
- Only starting a single program
- I booted up Windows (on a separate hard drive), which is working perfectly fine and fast
- Ran a disk self-test on the SSD Ubuntu is installed on, it came back as "Disk is OK".

None of this worked. Since it's not a problem or running out of RAM or CPU power I'm quite unsure what could have caused it to become so slow after being very pleasantly fast for half a year.

My specs:

- CPU: i7-7700K (aging model but working well under Windows)
- 32 GB RAM
- RTX 3060 Ti Graphics Card
- Gigabyte Z270-HD3P Mainboard

Since my dual-boot Windows works very well I can narrow down the problem to the Linux Software or the SSD that Ubuntu is installed on.

Any pointers are greatly appreciated!

Comment: Was the hard drive light blinking?  A while back, Ubuntu was doing an `updatedb` to index the files on the computer.  That noticeably slowed down the computer.  It wasn't a high resource process; just something that occupies the disk.

Comment: 1. Open system monitor and check if there is some process which is consuming a lot of CPU cycles. 2. Try changing the graphics driver in the Additional Drivers tab of `Software & Sources`.

Comment: @Ray thanks for the idea! I don't have an HDD light because it's an SSD without any indicators.

Comment: @ArchismanPanigrahi as I said, CPU usage is very low.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason turned out to be a faulty SSD. I reinstalled Ubuntu, but the problem did not go away, so I could exclude a software problem.

Thus, the only possible culprit left was the SSD (because it was the only hardware component that wasn't also in use by the perfectly working Windows dual-boot installation).

I exchanged the SSD and everything was fast again.

The fault mode was very weird though. It was just extremely slow reading. Eventually, it read everything correctly, it was just taking extremely long to do it. Maybe a broken cache?

I know that it read perfectly fine because I didn't clean-install Ubuntu on the new SSD but I copied the partition over from the old one - everything works perfectly on the new SSD now.

Comment: If it happens with the new SSD, check the temps on the drive. I've had similar issues when the drive was overheating, everything was throttled.